# GUI Functions Contain Ajax Calls, can I chain GUI Functions?

Tags: jquery, ajax

In my code I have GUI functions that have some business logic and then call Ajax sub-functions. The examples **Add / Delete / Update Activity**.

The **Add/Delete** are coded already. The **Update** GUI function is `Delete->Add`, so I'd like to chain the GUI functions **Delete/Add** that call their respective Ajax functions. But is this possible? I don't have access to the underlying Promises. I'd like to keep the encapsulated business logic of the GUI functions.

Suppose I have this:

```
function deleteActivity() {
   // 1. ... do some business logic first
   // 2. Call respective Ajax method
   var promise = ajaxDeleteActivity(id);
   promise.then(function() { 
       //...
   });
}

function addActivity(id) {
   // 1. ... do some business logic first
   // 2. Call respective Ajax method
   var promise = ajaxAddActivity(id);
   promise.then(function() { 
       //...
   });
}

function updateActivity(id) {
   // I'd like to chain the GUI functions w/business logic, but since I don't have 
   // access to the underlying Promises, I'm not really chaining them!
   // 1.
   deleteActivity(id);
   // 2.
   addActivity(newId);
}
```

Comment: Without access to the promises returned from the delete/add functions (or even to provide callback functions as arguments) then you cannot chain the requests.

Comment: I have the promises returned from the Ajax functions. But I can't return those promises in the GUI functions, can I? I would need a "return.." in the .then(), is that possible?

Comment: If you make the delete and add functions return the promise objects then it's fairly straightforward I think. There's nothing obviously in the above sample stopping you from doing this.

Comment: @geneb.: What GUI functions do you mean? Are any of the above "GUI functions"?

Comment: The GUI functions are deleteActivity/addActivity. They call separate functions that return Ajax promises, called ajaxDeleteActivity/ajaxAddActivty.

Comment: Alternatively why can't updateActivity call ajaxAddActivity and ajaxDeleteActivity directly? Then you don't get any unexpected GUI side effects intended only for those specific actions, and can do GUI actions which are appropriate for an update. I wouldn't create coupling between the GUI actions if you don't have to. BTW if these addActivity/deleteActivity functions are "GUI" functions, then they shouldn't really contain "business logic" as mentioned in your comments. They should just update the GUI. Business logic should be handled one layer back from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have the promises returned from the Ajax functions. But I can't return those promises in the GUI functions, can I?

Yes, you can — just return the result of `then`:

```
function deleteActivity() {
   // 1. ... do some business logic first
   // 2. Call respective Ajax method
   var promise = ajaxDeleteActivity(id);
   return promise.then(function() { 
// ^^^^^^------------------------------------------ ****
       //...
   });
}

function addActivity(id) {
   // 1. ... do some business logic first
   // 2. Call respective Ajax method
   var promise = ajaxAddActivity(id);
   return promise.then(function() { 
// ^^^^^^------------------------------------------ ****
       //...
   });
}
```

...and then *(no pun)* use it:

```
function updateActivity(id) {
   // I'd like to chain the GUI functions w/business logic, but since I don't have 
   // access to the underlying Promises, I'm not really chaining them!
   // 1.
   return deleteActivity(id).then(function() {
// ^^^^^^------------------------------------------ ****
       // 2.
       return addActivity(newId);
//     ^^^^^^-------------------------------------- ****
   });
}
```

Remember that a call to `then` (or `catch`) creates a new promise (let's call it `newPromise`), which is then settled based on what the `then`/`catch` callback does (returns a value, returns a promise, or throws an error). If the callback returns a value, `newPromise` is resolved with that value. If the callback returns a promise, `newPromise` is resolved/rejected based on whether that promise resolves or rejects. If the callback throws an error, `newPromise` is rejected with that error.

Since we've returned the result of `then` in `updateActivity` above, other things can build on it as well.